# How to reload .profile within ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux

I am using Ruby 2, I resource some environment variable and put them into ~/.profile , Then i reload .profile within ruby script as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env
`source ~/.profile`
```

But i got source command not found.How to reload .profile within ruby script?

I also tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env
`/bin/bash -c 'source ~/.profile'`
```

But didn’t got success.

Answer (score 0):

In short - you can't.

The sourced environment variables are only valid in the subprocess, it won't affect the parent process.

The only way would be to use `bash -c "source ~/.profile; env"` to return the environment variables, and then parse and set them in your script.

Comment: I dont wants to use the variable in script, I only wants to set environment variable in parent shell permanently so that when script finished those variables should be available to parent process. Can i do that?

Comment: No, you can't change the environment variables of the parent from a child process.